# How to view Unicode characters Paragraph Separator and Line Separator in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, unicode, characters, textwrangler

How can I see Unicode characters [Paragraph Separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) and [Line Separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) in Notepad++? If I select View - Show Symbol - Show All Characters, I still can't see these two characters. For example in TextWrangler these characters are shown as question marks when I select to see all the hidden characters. Is there any way to see these characters in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

The newest version (6.7) shows U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR as an upper dot (like the middle dot “·” but in a higher position). It does not show U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR at all, as stated in the question. Since “Show Symbol” is the way to control things like this, we can be pretty sure that there isn’t a way to make PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR visible.

By the way, the situation is similar in the BabelPad editor, but in it, you can use the Convert Toolbar to convert characters to their U+.... notations like U+2029.